# Classicthesis - Lowering header on specific pages only

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, classicthesis, scrlayer-scrpage, typearea

Assume a document using the `classicthesis` package in which some pages follow `\pagestyle{plain}`, while others follow `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` (back and forth several times). My goal is to lower the header on all pages following `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` by 1cm, yet leave the headheight on pages following `\pagestyle{plain}` unchanged.

I have tried several settings, including (a) increasing the option `headheight` by 1cm in the class definition while `\vfill`ing the `\rohead`, (b) adding a `\raisebox{-\1.0cm}{}` around the `\rohead` content, and (c) increasing the top-margin via the `geometry` package by 1cm, yet the header height does not budge. However, I cannot find any line that would hard-code the header height in the classicthesis style file either.

How do I lower the header on all pages following `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` by 1cm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```latex
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}
  {\Ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.head}{\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.5cm]{#1}}{}}
```

to move all head layers of page style `scrheadings` 0.5cm down.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\ihead*{\currentpagestyle}% to show the used page style and the position of page header

\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}
  {\Ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.head}{\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.5cm]{#1}}{}}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remark: `plain` is an alias of layer page style `plain.scrheadings`.

Comment: Thank you for your proposed solution. Your MWE works fine, but when I include the for-loop lines in my document, I receive `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}` and `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.` These errors occur irrespective of where prior to the beginning of the document I place the two lines.

Comment: I can replicate the error when inserting the two lines you proposed at line 58 of `ClassicThesis.tex`of classicthesis v4.6

Comment: Sorry, but I can not reproduce your issue using an uptodate TL 2021 or an uptodate MiKTeX.

Comment: You just need the following three files for recreating the issue: [Thesis_Michael.tex](https://pastebin.com/sxKsWzTN), [classicthesis-config.tex](https://pastebin.com/Pgm1mHuS), and [classicthesis.sty](https://pastebin.com/bSVtPNnd). I compiled via `pdflatex`.

Comment: Do not use `\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{...}` in the argument of `\textbf`! Change `\textbf{\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{...}}` to `\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{...}`.

Comment: Yes, the `\textbf` command was the issue. Thanks for pointing this out. Great answer in general.